# Sum and replace columns with same name R for a data frame containing different classes

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing multiple classes, I would like to sum those columns that have the same name and are numeric, and replace the old columns with the new sum, does anyone know a way to do this?

i.e I have a data frame like:

```
col1 col2  col3 col3 
char factor int int
```

I would like to produce

```
col1  col2  col3 
char factor 2int
```

I have previously used:

```
data <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, by(t(data),INDICES=names(data),FUN=colSums)))
```

However this was on a dataframe that only had numeric variables.

There are other examples on the internet but not meeting the conditions of: replacement, preserving the rest of the frame, and of being on a frame with multiple classes

Similar question: [how do I search for columns with same name, add the column values and replace these columns with same name by their sum? Using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938491/how-do-i-search-for-columns-with-same-name-add-the-column-values-and-replace-th)

Comment: Do you have cases where two `col2` `col2` are not of the same class?

Comment: @akrun No all the columns with the same name are the same classes (numeric)

Comment: Isn't this just `data$new_col <- rowSums(data[sapply(data, is.integer)])` and then remove these columns?

Comment: @DavidArenburg It has to match the duplicated column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
dat1 <- dat #to keep a copy of the original dataset 
indx <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)#check which columns are numeric
nm1 <- which(indx)#get the numeric index of the column
indx2 <- duplicated(names(nm1))#check which among the
# integer columns are duplicated
#use `Map` after splitting the "nm1" with its "names", do the `rowSums`
dat[ nm1[!indx2]] <- Map(function(x,y) rowSums(x[y]), list(dat),
                                       split(nm1, names(nm1)))

 dat[ -nm1[indx2]]
```

#### Update

Or to make it more efficient, only take the "duplicated" and "numeric" columns while leaving the others intact. Create an "index" (`indx2`) of columns that are duplicated.  Subset the "nm1" based on the "indx2" and then do `rowSums` as described above. Finally, remove the unwanted columns (duplicated ones) by using the "indx3"

```
 indx2 <- duplicated(names(nm1))|duplicated(names(nm1),fromLast=TRUE)
 nm2 <- nm1[indx2]
 indx3 <- duplicated(names(nm2))
 dat[nm2[!indx3]] <- Map(function(x,y) rowSums(x[y]), 
                list(dat),split(nm2, names(nm2)))
 datN <- dat[ -nm2[indx3]]
 datN
 #    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 #1    16   23    2   10   10
 #2    10   18   12    8   18
 #3    21   23   15    6   10
 #4    14   37    3    5   15
 #5    29   39    5    1   11
 #6    26   31   14    2   20
 #7    25   31    2    8   10
 #8    36   31   12    8    6
 #9    32   26   13    6    4
 #10   16   38    1    7    3
```

Checking the results

```
 rowSums(dat1[names(dat1) %in% 'col1'])
 #[1] 16 10 21 14 29 26 25 36 32 16
 rowSums(dat1[names(dat1) %in% 'col2'])
 #[1] 23 18 23 37 39 31 31 31 26 38
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(col1 = c(6L, 5L, 15L, 11L, 14L, 19L, 6L, 16L, 
17L, 6L), col2 = c(13L, 8L, 14L, 14L, 7L, 19L, 4L, 1L, 11L, 3L
), col3 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "5", "12", "13", "14", "15"), class = "factor"), col2 = c(7L, 
5L, 8L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 20L), col4 = structure(c(7L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "10"), class = "factor"), col5 = c(10L, 18L, 10L, 
15L, 11L, 20L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 3L), col1 = c(10L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 15L, 
7L, 19L, 20L, 15L, 10L), col2 = c(3L, 5L, 1L, 20L, 13L, 7L, 12L, 
17L, 1L, 15L)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col2", "col4", 
"col5", "col1", "col2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution very nice code! Do you know if it's possible to pass the reorder function to rowSums the way you have written it?

Comment: Is it possible to modify your answer to preserve the row ordering? 
I made a mistake, I meant pass the 'reorder' argument to the 'rowSums' function.

Comment: @user1987097 In the example I created, the row order is preserved.  Not sure why it is not preserved

Comment: @user1987097 If you look at the code, I am not doing anything to change the row order.

Comment: The reorder argument to the rowsums function defaults to TRUE, if you don't supply it with reorder = FALSE it will do it automatically. 
This is problematic for datasets in which ordering is important.

Comment: @user1987097  I couldn't find any `reorder` argument within `rowSums` From the help page, `rowSums (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1)`

Comment: If that is the case, another option would be `Map(function(x,y) do.call(`+`, x[y]` (not tested)

Comment: Apologies I was looking at the "rowsum" function not "rowSums"

Comment: @user1987097  It's okay. `rowSums` will be pretty fast.  If this answers your question...