# Replace Column Names With String Right of "_"

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe (d3) which has some column names with "Date_Month.Year", I want to replace those column names with just "Month.Year" so if there are multiple columns with the same "Month.Year" they will just be a summed column.

Below is the code I tried and the output

```
library(stringr)

print(colnames(d3))
 #below is output of the print statement
 #[1] "ProductCategoryDesc" "RegionDesc"          "SourceDesc"          "variable"           
 #[5] "2019-02-28_Feb.2019" "2019-03-01_Mar.2019" "2019-03-04_Mar.2019" "2019-03-05_Mar.2019"
 #[9] "2019-03-06_Mar.2019" "2019-03-07_Mar.2019" "2019-03-08_Mar.2019" 

d3 <- d3 %>% mutate(col = str_remove(col, '*._'))
```

Here is the error I get: 
 Evaluation error: argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to).

So I got the first part of my problem answered I used to get all column names in Month.Year format but now I am having issues with summing the columns that have the same name, for that I looked at [Sum and replace columns with same name R for a data frame containing different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839449/sum-and-replace-columns-with-same-name-r-for-a-data-frame-containing-different-c)

```
colnames(d3) <- gsub('.*_', '', colnames(d3))
```

Below is the code I used to get the columns summed that have a duplicate name, however with this code it is not necessarily putting the summed values in the correct columns.

```
indx <- sapply(d3, is.numeric)#check which columns are numeric
nm1 <- which(indx)#get the numeric index of the column
indx2 <- duplicated(names(nm1))|duplicated(names(nm1),fromLast=TRUE)
nm2 <- nm1[indx2]
indx3 <- duplicated(names(nm2))
d3[nm2[!indx3]] <- Map(function(x,y) rowSums(x[y],na.rm = FALSE), 
                        list(d3),split(nm2, names(nm2)))
d3 <- d3[ -nm2[indx3]]
```

Comment: Maybe you need to think differently. You may want to `gather` all your columns into a column of names and a column of values. Then, `separate` or `extract` the names into a new column, and finally `group_by` + `summarise` your values. These functions are in {tidyr} and {dplyr}. With a reproducible example, it would be easier to show you an answer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the column names, you should be changing `colnames`:

```
colnames(d3) <- gsub('.*_', '', colnames(d3))
```

Note, in your regex, quantifiers (ie `*`) go after the thing they quantify. So it should be `.*_` rather than `*._`

An example where we remove text before a `.` in `iris`:

```
colnames(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     

# In regex, . means any character, so to match an actual '.',
#   we need to 'escape' it with \\.
colnames(iris) <- gsub('.*\\.', '', colnames(iris))

colnames(iris)
[1] "Length"  "Width"   "Length"  "Width"   "Species"
```

Comment: Now from that how would I make duplicated column names just be one, so sum them, if you know?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking for this question: [Sum all columns whose names start with a pattern, by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32052723/8366499). If you have questions about doing that which the linked question doesn't solve, please ask another question about that problem. We like to keep each question focused on one problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
colnames(d3) <- sapply(colnames(d3), function(colname){
    return( str_remove(colname, '.*_') )
})
```

The regex should be ".*_" to match the case you need

Comment: I get this error Warning: Error in stri_replace_first_regex: Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX). Maybe there is an issue since some columns would have the same name and those column values have to be summed?

Comment: .*_ should be the regex string, you mistyped dot :)